# Matlab filter implementation

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design, transfer-function, digital-filters

I have a filter response in the $z$-domain.

$$H_0(z) = 2 + 6z^{−1} + z^{−2} + 5z^{−3} + z^{−5}$$

How do I implement this filter on MATLAB?

I can do this if I have the coefficients but I do not know how to get them.

Comment: Welcome here. It seems that a first step is to get the coefficients. What type of filter does this equation model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter is a 5-tap delay line FIR filter. The FIR filter's coefficients are `[2 6 1 5 1]`. If `x` is your filter's input sequence and you execute the following MATLAB command:

```
h = [2 6 1 5 1];
```

you can then implement the filter (to produce a `y` output sequence) using the following MATLAB command:

```
y = filter(h, 1, x);
```

You can see your filter's frequency magnitude and phase responses by executing the following MATLAB command:

```
freqz(h, 1, 256)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be [2 6 1 5 0 1] since there is no $z^{-4}$ term?

Comment: yes it shoud be [2 6 1 5 0 1]. Thank to you all

Comment: Yes yes! [2 6 1 5 0 1] is correct. Sorry for the confusion.